# Connected supports

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, connectedness

Consider any measure $\mu\in\Delta(\mathbb{R})$ and let $F_{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ be the distribution function induced by $\mu$.

We know that if $F_{\mu}$ is continuous, then $\text{supp}(\mu)$, the support of the measure $\mu$, is a perfect set in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** Under what conditions it is possible to say that $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is *connected*?

A cantor distribution is continuous, has a perfect support, but not a connected one. Nevertheless, it is not absolutely continuous. Is absolutely continuity (w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure) sufficient to ensure a connected support?

Comment: Well, under what conditions over the distribution function can we say that its support is connected. It can be perfect and connected. But it is not the case that when is perfect, it is also connected, right?

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is closed, it is disconnected iff there is an entire interval in its complement which is between two points of $\text{supp}(\mu)$.  An interval in its complement is just an interval on which $F_\mu$ is constant, and being between two points of $\text{supp}(\mu)$ just means that $F_\mu$ changes both before and after that interval, or equivalently that the constant value on the interval is not $0$ or $1$.  So $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is connected iff there does not exist any (nondegenerate) interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $F_\mu$ is constant on $I$ with value different from $0$ and $1$.

Another equivalent condition would be that if $a=\inf\{t:F_\mu(t)>0\}$ and $b=\sup\{t:F_\mu(t)<1\}$, then $F_\mu$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[a,b]$, since if it were not strictly increasing it would have to be constant on some subinterval.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. Just to make sure here I am not assuming unnecessary things: absolute continuity does not imply (neither is implied by) connected support, correct?

Comment: That is correct.